# Cómo solucionar el problema con las librerías al crear el .jar de mi app

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo un problema cuando intento generar el .jar de mi aplicación, Netbeans me manda el siguiente mensaje de error:

> ant -f C:\Users\siste\Documents\Proyectos\systop -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild
> clean jar
> init:
> deps-clean:
> Updating property file: C:\Users\siste\Documents\Proyectos\systop\build\built-
> clean.properties
> Deleting directory C:\Users\siste\Documents\Proyectos\systop\build
> clean:
> init:
> deps-jar:
> Created dir: C:\Users\siste\Documents\Proyectos\systop\build
> Updating property file: C:\Users\siste\Documents\Proyectos\systop\build\built-
> jar.properties
> Created dir: C:\Users\siste\Documents\Proyectos\systop\build\classes
> Created dir: C:\Users\siste\Documents\Proyectos\systop\build\empty
> Created dir: C:\Users\siste\Documents\Proyectos\systop\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
> Compiling 304 source files to C:\Users\siste\Documents\Proyectos\systop\build\classes
> C:\Users\siste\Documents\Proyectos\systop\src\Vistas\frmLogin.java:21: error: package com.formdev.flatlaf.intellijthemes does not exist
> import com.formdev.flatlaf.intellijthemes.FlatArcOrangeIJTheme;
> C:\Users\siste\Documents\Proyectos\systop\src\Vistas\frmPrincipal.java:11: error: package com.formdev.flatlaf.intellijthemes does not exist
> import com.formdev.flatlaf.intellijthemes.FlatArcOrangeIJTheme;
> C:\Users\siste\Documents\Proyectos\systop\src\Vistas\frmLogin.java:278: error: cannot find symbol
> UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new FlatArcOrangeIJTheme());
> symbol:   class FlatArcOrangeIJTheme
> location: class frmLogin
> C:\Users\siste\Documents\Proyectos\systop\src\Vistas\frmPrincipal.java:3105: error: cannot find symbol
> UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new FlatArcOrangeIJTheme());
> symbol:   class FlatArcOrangeIJTheme
> location: class frmPrincipal
> Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> 4 errors
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: _com.formdev.flatlaf.intellijthemes does not exist_. ¿Existe?

Comment: Si, de hecho si ejecuto la aplicación desde Netbeans, no me da ningún error